# Docker-Compose Skip Proxy for local daemon

Tags: proxy, docker, docker-for-windows

I am running docker engine installed on Windows. I have the daemon exposed on :2375.

I have the docker and docker-compose CLI installed on WSL ("Bash for Windows").

I am behind a corporate proxy and everything seems to be working fine with my environmental variables set and proxies set to bypass for 127.0.0.1 and localhost in the docker engine GUI.

However, docker-compose results in a proxy error. It appears that docker-compose is reaching out to my corporate proxy to reach the daemon running on localhost. How can this be resolved? I already have 127.0.0.1 and localhost exluded in the docker engine exclusion configuration.

```
ajohnson@232341-PC:~/concourse$ docker-compose --verbose ps
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/ajohnson/.docker/config.json', '/home/ajohnson/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/ajohnson/.docker/config.json', '/home/ajohnson/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
urllib3.connectionpool._new_conn: Starting new HTTP connection (1): proxy.company.org:80
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://proxy.company.org:80 "GET http://localhost:2375/v1.25/version HTTP/1.1" 504 3676
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
    command()
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
    project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 42, in project_from_options
    compatibility=options.get('--compatibility'),
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 123, in get_project
    host=host, environment=environment
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 97, in get_client
    version_info = six.iteritems(client.version())
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result
    self._raise_for_status(response)
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/ajohnson/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)
docker.errors.APIError: 504 Server Error: Gateway Timeout ("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Notification: Gateway Timeout</title>
```

")

Answer (score 1):

this issue has been addressed here:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6706

> set NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.* Compose should read this variable and
>   not use the company proxy to access the daemon on localhost